# Javascript handling responses

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, httpwebresponse

I have a angularjs function which is calling a server side url and getting responses. This server side some times returning a xml response. sometimes returning a blog as the response. Can't predict. If I set the response type to "blob" in client side, it is showing image properly. But I cannot handle non blob responses because of xml responses also showing as a blob. Searched a lot in web about converting blob to xml(response containing a xml response). But couldn't find an answer :(

If I remove the response type: "blob", can handle the non blob response but cannot handle blob response.

Is there a way to handle both type of responses in a single method?

this is my angularjs code for getting response

```
 $http({
            url: apiConstants.BASE_URL + 'login',
            method: "POST",
            responseType: "blob",
            data: {
                "Req": req
            },
            headers: {
                'X-Username': aUser,
                'X-Password': aPass,
                "Content-Type": "application/xml"
            },
            dataType: "xml"
        }).success(function(data, status) {
           console.log(data);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can manage to set the `Content-Type` header **correctly** in the response while serving your blob and xml responses from your server, then you can use the `headers()` in success callback to handle them accordingly.

```
$http.post(url, postData)
     .then(function(response){
        // success callback
        var responseType = response.headers('Content-Type');
        var actualType = responseType.split(';');
        if(actualType[0] === 'application/xml'){
          // handle XML files here
        }else{
          // handle blob files here
        }
     }, function(error){
        // error callback
     });
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. In my case, response doesn't have headers attribute. response.headers('Content-Type'); returning an error.when I logged the response in the console it looks like this      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AuthInfo>
    <token>123456</token>
    <AuthStatus>
        <Id>200</Id>
        <Description>LOGIN_OK</Description>
    </AuthStatus>
</AuthInfo>

Comment: Can't you set the headers by changing your server side code ? Ideally we are supposed to set the `Content-Type` header to reflect the response type that we're committing from server

Comment: in my browser it is showing response header like this.Content-Type: application/xml;charset=utf-8. But I cannot read response header values. it shows "TypeError: response.headers is not a function" error

Comment: Strange. what is the version of Angular that you're using ? Here's a sample [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zroOOO?editors=101) showcasing the idea of checking response headers

Comment: Are you using `then()` with success callback like I did (or) are you using `success()` from your original code ?

Comment: I am using success() finction

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by doing following changes

```
$http({
        url: apiConstants.BASE_URL + 'login',
        method: "POST",
        responseType: "blob",
        data: {
            "Req": req
        },
        headers: {
            'X-Username': aUser,
            'X-Password': aPass,
            "Content-Type": "application/xml"
        },
        dataType: "xml"
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       var responseType = headers('Content-Type');

            if(responseType === 'application/xml;charset=utf-8'){
                alert("xml");
            }else{
                alert("blob");
            }
    }
```